# Sending a URL in a GET request to a Python server on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, parameters, server, get-request

I have written a very simple server in Python on Google Apps engine. I want to be able to send it a command via a GET request, such as `"http://myserver.appspot.com/?do=http://webpage.com/?secondary=parameter"`

This does not work, as the secondary parameter gets interpreted separately and sent to my app as well.
Any help?

Comment: This isn't really a question about GAE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url `http://myserver.appspot.com/?do=http://webpage.com/?secondary=parameter` is uncorrectly formed. Perhaps you can `urlencode` the string data and then send it

```
from urllib import urlencode
data = {"do": "http://webpage.com/?secondary=parameter"}
encoded_data = urlencode(data)
url = "http://myserver.appspot.com/?" + encoded_data
```

Gives output

```
>>> print url
http://myserver.appspot.com/?do=http%3A%2F%2Fwebpage.com%2F%3Fsecondary%3Dparameter
```

Alternatively, if you are using python [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) module, you can do

```
import requests
payload = {"do": "http://webpage.com/?secondary=parameter"}
r = requests.get("http://myserver.appspot.com/", params=payload)
```

which gives output

```
>>> print r.url
u'http://myserver.appspot.com/?do=http%3A%2F%2Fwebpage.com%2F%3Fsecondary%3Dparameter'
```